# install VMWare hypervisor on a machine that has already windows 10

Tags: windows-10, esxi

I am trying to understand if I can run hypervisor beside windows 10, or if I need a machine that has just hypervisor on.

The site is not really helpful, I did get the iso but I have to reboot from it to test, so before going that route I thought it is better to ask around.

I would like to run it side by side with my w10 installation, if possible; but if I need to run the hypervisor on its own, I am fine too.

Comment: You will have to uninstall Hyper-V if you want to install VMWare Workstation.

Comment: you mean in the bios? Or there is also an option on Windows that use Hyper-V?

Comment: **No,** I don't mean the firmware, I actually do mean, you have to uninstall Hyper-V.  I choose my words very carefully for a reason.  I didn't indicate you shoudl disable VT-x which would be in the firmware.  *You still need to leave VT-x enabled.*

Comment: As some background: Vmweare is not a program. It is a firm making a ton of programs, including 1) vmware player. 2) vmware workstation. 3) vmware fusion. 4) vmware server. 5) esx 6) esxi.  The latters are often referred to as bare metal hypervisors. Could you plase add the relevant tag and remove the generic [vmware tag ?

Comment: Done, I didn't think that would matter, due to the context of the question. I did put down ESXi, which is the name of the VMWare hypervisor product (V6.5.0)

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to run a hypervisor 'inside' Windows 10? Are you trying to run a hypervisor on bare metal, with Windows 10 'inside' the hypervisor? Or are you wanting to run the hypervisor and Windows 10 both on baremetal at the same time, one 'beside' the other?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean "VMWare hypervisor" as in the actual VMWare product(VSphere or ESXi or whatever they're calling it now), then you would need to install that in place of Windows.

You could then install Windows inside of a container(a.k.a. a Virtual Machine) VSphere/ESXi creates for it.

If you're just looking to learn virtualization basics though, start with VirtualBox/HyperV/(I forget the name of the one for Apples)/etc. Those you can run from within Windows.

[Edit: forgot about VMWare Workstation, but falls under the second group, too]

Comment: I see, so the ESXi server need to be the only thing running on the machine to work; I was hoping it could co-exist with Windows and run as service.